# Make Sails use correct CoffeeScript version

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, sails.js

For my Sails project, I need CoffeeScript 2.x. Here's what I've done:

- Completely removed coffeescript from my system
- `npm install coffeescript@next --save`

`packages.json` shows the following in my dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
  "coffeescript": "^2.0.0-beta2",
// ...
```

When I manually compile a controller:

```
node-modules/.bin/coffee -c api/controllers/MyController.coffee
```

I get the correct output. However, when I start Sails (`node --inspect app.js`) I can see in the debugger that the controller got compiled with an older version of coffeescript. How is that even possible, since 2.0.0-beta2 is the only version installed?

How can I make Sails use the correct version of CoffeeScript?

Answer (score 0):

After pulling out most of my hair, I finally got something that works. It isn't an ideal solution, though, so better ideas are welcome.

1. Fork `grunt-contrib-coffee`, edit its `package.json` to depend on the version of CoffeeScript I need.
2. Fork `grunt` and make similar edits.
3. Fork `sails` and edit the relevant branch to update the dependencies, which are now specified as `github:mssever/grunt` and `github:mssever/grunt-contrib-coffee`. There's also a direct coffeescript dependency to update.
4. Edit the project `package.json` to reflect the above dependencies.
5. Uninstall the system-wide `sails` and manually remove the symlink under `myproject/node-modules`, or you will get hard-to-understand permissions errors.
6. *Finally!* Run `npm update`. Don't even think about what will happen if you need to make further updates, as it'll be a real headache.

Answer (score 0):

You can also get it to work if you link coffeescript to coffee-script in both the global and the sails node_modules directory.  It's still a hack, but might be less work to get it going.

To be precise here are the step by step instructions:

1) Install both coffeescript and sails globally, with npm -g, that puts them both in the directory /usr/local/lib/node_modules/

```
npm install -g coffeescript
npm install -g sails
```

2)  Go into the install directory and link coffeescript to coffee-script

```
cd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffeescript 
ln -s coffeescript coffee-script
```

3) Go into the sails node_modules directory, rename coffee-script to something else, and link the name to the global coffeescript

```
cd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules
mv coffee-script coffee-script-old
ln -s /usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffeescript coffee-script
```

This seemed to work for me, I can finally use async/await in my coffeescript without sails blowing up, but I'd be interested on finding out the correct solution.